# Overlay property with fixed container working bad

Tags: css

I created an example on:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-ganguly-7rpi6?file=/index.html

In the documentation I see:

> Behaves the same as auto, but with the scrollbars drawn on top of content instead of taking up space. Only supported in WebKit-based (e.g., Safari) and Blink-based (e.g., Chrome or Opera) browsers.

In my cases, overflow should be working as the same as hidden (equals values with and without scrollbar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the unit you use for the width of your header, instead of `100%` you should use `100vw`. This is because percetage unit doesn't include the width of the scrollbar, the viewport unit includes everything that is in the viewport of the window, so your header will stretch to the end behind the scrollbar when it's painted above the contents.